# DHCP Server Port-Based Address Allocation switch cisco 2960

Tags: cisco, dhcp

In my work they asked me to configure a switch cisco 2960 and to the switch we will connect printers, they want that the switch gives the ip to the printers with DHCP (we dont have a dhcp server) and they also want that in each individual port an ip would be assigned, doesnt matter if they change the printer they want the same ip address assign this is in case a printer fails and they want only to replace it and dont have to do anything about configurations. I have configured DHCP Server Port-Based Address Allocation but it isnt working

I used this guide  http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dhcp/configuration/xe-3se/5700/dhcp-prt-bsd-aa.pdf

but it isnt assigning anything.

Answer (score 0):

Tough to give a good answer without seeing your config. I'm going to assume you've checked you're running a version of code that supports this and that you've checked for typos.

Given that, I can only see one thing. In the doc you've linked to, it shows the syntax for the assignment being:

```
ip dhcp pool dhcppool
network 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0
address 10.1.1.7 client-id Et1/0 ascii
```

In this [document](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960/software/release/12.2_55_se/configuration/guide/swdhcp82.html#wp1320905) which is specifically for the 2960, it shows quotes round the Et1/0. So you have:

```
ip dhcp pool dhcppool
network 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0
address 10.1.1.7 client-id "Et1/0" ascii
```

Beyond that, is it bulking at a certain point or is it taking all the commands?

I don't have a 2960 here to test it, so this is the best I can do.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I fixed it, when I was typing the address I typed the interface with lowercase as soon as I write it like this Fa0/1 it worked. I was writing it like this fa0/1 and that was why didn't was working :)